# File access issue in C# application running on mac using mono

Tags: c#, mono

I developed a simple .net application that scrapes some data from web and saves it in a file (file and the proejct exe file are in the same folder ).

It runs fine on windows, but when i run it on mac using 'Mono' i get this error

> Access to the path '[path]' is denied.

I am creating the accessing this file using Directory.GetCurrentDirectory.

here is the path i am using:

```
 System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\abc.csv";
```

Comment: Looks like a permissions issue. Make sure the account the application runs under has the correct permissions for the directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not concatenate directories using strings, not if you want your applications to be cross platform.

**BAD**:

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\abc.csv";
```

**Good**:

```
Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "abc.csv");
```

Using `Path.Combine` will ensure the correct directory separators are used.

If you have to traverse through *several* directories, use `Path.Combine` repeatedly:

```
Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "mydir"), "abc.csv");
```

Comment: Here is the indication "\\abc.csv" :)))

Comment: @Lu4 - Yes, which was **not** there when you answered. It was an educated guess on your side, but a guess non the less.

Comment: Path.Combine also accepts a infinite number of arguments, so you can do something like this: `Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "mydir", "abc.csv");`

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are using wrong slashes on windows you would use something like "Path\to\my\file" but on mac the slashes are reversed to "Path/to/my/file"

Comment: Are you using `Path.Combine` to merge directory and file names?

Comment: There is no indication that this is the case from the post - this is pure guesswork. It is _unlikely_ that `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory` will have the wrong slashes, right?

Comment: here is the path i am using System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\abc.csv";

Comment: i am not using Path.Combine .

Comment: :))) use System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/abc.csv"